# Getting a collection of tags from XML based on certain attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml file

```
<config>
  <PersonMapping>
    <Field>
      <Name>Id</Name>
      <Position>0</Position>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>FirstName</Name>
      <Position>1</Position>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>LastName</Name>
      <Position>2</Position>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name insert='false' update='false'>Address1</Name>
      <Position>3</Position>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name insert='false' update='false'>Address2</Name>
      <Position>4</Position>
    </Field>
  </PersonMapping>
</config>
```

I have to create two collections based on settings in this file.
Depending on the users needs certain 'Field' tag may or may not have the 'insert' and 'update' attributes.

Insert collection will have all the tags which have insert = 'true' or not present
Update collection will have all the tags which have update = 'true' or not present

For the tags that don't have either of them they are true by default.

I wrote this query for insert

```
propertiesToInsertFromXML = from nameTag in xml.Element("Config").Element("PersonMapping").Elements("Field")
                            let insert = nameTag.Element("Name").Attribute("insert")
                            let update = nameTag.Element("Name").Attribute("update")
                            where insert == null || (bool)insert  && update == null || (bool)update
                            select nameTag.Element("Name").Value;
```

Which gives Name, FirstName, LastName

Can someone help me here?

Regards.

Comment: "does not give the required result" isn't nearly enough information. What does it do, compared with what you wanted it to do? (I note you're not using `update` at all, by the way.)

Comment: Edited the question to show the result of the query.

Comment: It would really help if you'd edit your post to format the XML nicely, too. It's very hard to read at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast attribute to nullable boolean. For missing attributes you will get nulls. Then just verify if `insert` do not have value (attribute is missing) or if its value is `true`:

```
var insertTags = from name in xml.Descendants("Name")
                 let insert = (bool?)name.Attribute("insert") 
                 where !insert.HasValue || insert.Value
                 select (string)name;
```

**Remark:** `insert` variable has type `Nullable<bool>` it is not of `XAttribute` type here.

---

Same with XPath:

```
var insertTags = xml.XPathSelectElements("//Name[@insert='true'or not(@insert)]")
                    .Select(n => (string)n);
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus no, you don't need to use Value property. Explicit cast operator will do that

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus nope, I'm not using Value of attribute node anywhere. Previously (before edit) it was `!insert.HasValue || insert == true`, which also works

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yep, `insert` has `Nullable<bool>` type

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change the `where` part to

```
where (insert == null || Convert.ToBoolean(insert.Value))
```

EDIT
Don't know if `<Name insert='fasle'` is desired for test or a typo.